# Vimeo player doesn't get "finish" event

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, video, vimeo

I have a very basic JS that works when the vimeo iframe finishes the video. Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vy9kf0w5/1/

How can I target the finish of the video with JS? It looks like it should work :p

```
document.getElementById('video').api_addEventListener('finish', function(event) {
    alert('video has ended');
    console.log('video has ended');
   $('#video').addClass('finished');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/vy9kf0w5/3/

You need to include Vimeo's [Froogaloop](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript) script in your page in order to get events from Vimeo videos. Then it is very simple, on their supported events just do what you want :) The only other thing you need to do is to add ?api=1&player_id=video to the url :)

iframe

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/55874553?api=1&player_id=video&title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=c9ff23;autoplay=1" width="720" height="405"  id="video" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

The CODE

```
var iframe = $('#video')[0],
    player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {       
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

function onFinish(id) {
    alert('video has ended');
    console.log('video has ended');
    $('#vimeoembed').addClass('finished');
}
```

Read more about Vimeos javaScript API [here](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api)